# How can I get the offset and data from the text section of a shared libray?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, openssl, aes

I build OpenSSL-1.0.2n  with -g 386 shared option (to work with basic assembly version) to generate shared library libcrypto.so.1.0.0.

Inside crypto/aes folder, aes-x86_64.s is generated and it has different global functions/labels.
The total numbers of lines in aes-x86_64.s is 2535 and various labels are present at different place (or line number in .s file).

```
328     .globl  AES_encrypt
        .type   AES_encrypt,@function
        .align  16
        .globl  asm_AES_encrypt
        .hidden asm_AES_encrypt
        asm_AES_encrypt:
334     AES_encrypt:


775     .globl  AES_decrypt
        .type   AES_decrypt,@function
        .align  16
        .globl  asm_AES_decrypt
        .hidden asm_AES_decrypt
        asm_AES_decrypt:
781     AES_decrypt:


844     .globl  private_AES_set_encrypt_key
        .type   private_AES_set_encrypt_key,@function
        .align  16
847     private_AES_set_encrypt_key:


1105    .globl  private_AES_set_decrypt_key
        .type   private_AES_set_decrypt_key,@function
        .align  16
1108    private_AES_set_decrypt_key:


1292    .globl  AES_cbc_encrypt
        .type   AES_cbc_encrypt,@function
        .align  16

        .globl  asm_AES_cbc_encrypt
        .hidden asm_AES_cbc_encrypt
        asm_AES_cbc_encrypt:
1299    AES_cbc_encrypt:


1750 .LAES_Te:
.long   0xa56363c6,0xa56363c6
.long   0x847c7cf8,0x847c7cf8
.long   0x997777ee,0x997777ee
.long   0x8d7b7bf6,0x8d7b7bf6
.long   0x0df2f2ff,0x0df2f2ff
.long   0xbd6b6bd6,0xbd6b6bd6

....
....


2140 .LAES_Td:
.long   0x50a7f451,0x50a7f451
.long   0x5365417e,0x5365417e
.long   0xc3a4171a,0xc3a4171a
.long   0x965e273a,0x965e273a
.long   0xcb6bab3b,0xcb6bab3b
```

**AES_cbc_encrypt** is global function declared at line number 776 and   label AES_cbc_encrypt is at line number 781.

local label **.LAES_Te** and **.LAES_Td** are at line number 1750 and 2140 respectively where long data are stored.

**I am able to access global label AES_cbc_encrypt of assembly file from another C program by linking with shared library.**

```
//test_glob.c
#include <stdlib.h> 

extern void* AES_cbc_encrypt() ;

int main()
{

    long *p;
    int i;
    p=(long *)(&AES_cbc_encrypt);
    for(i=0;i<768;i++)
    {
        printf("p+%d %p %x\n",i, p+i,*(p+i));
    }

}   

gcc test_glob.c -lcryto
./a.out 

This gives some random output and later segmentation fault.
```

There must be a way to find the **offset** of this data section (local label .LAES_Te and .LAES_Td) **from global label AES_cbc_encrypt** 
so that the data can be used in encryption/decryption.

I have following questions.

**1. How to find the offset from global label AES_cbc_encrypt to local label .LAES_Te and .LAES_Td so that based on 
that offset I can access data from another C program ?**

**2. Is there any other way to access those data of assembly file from C program ?**

**3. Is there any way to find the location in memory where those data is loaded and access those memory location to access data ?**

I am using gcc-5.4 Linux Ubuntu 16.04 . Any help or link will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

readelf -a aes-x86_64.o produces following output.

```
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 02 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
  Class:                             ELF64
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              REL (Relocatable file)
  Machine:                           Advanced Micro Devices X86-64
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x0
  Start of program headers:          0 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          14672 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x0
  Size of this header:               64 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           0 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         0
  Size of section headers:           64 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         16
  Section header string table index: 13

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type             Address           Offset        Size              EntSize          Flags  Link  Info  Align
  [ 0]                   NULL             0000000000000000  00000000        0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00000040        0000000000002e40  0000000000000000  AX       0     0     64
  [ 2] .rela.text        RELA             0000000000000000  00003808        0000000000000018  0000000000000018   I      14     1     8
  [ 3] .data             PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00002e80        0000000000000000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [ 4] .bss              NOBITS           0000000000000000  00002e80        0000000000000000  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1
  [ 5] .note.GNU-stack   PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00002e80        0000000000000000  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 6] .debug_line       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00002e80        00000000000005a4  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 7] .rela.debug_line  RELA             0000000000000000  00003820        0000000000000018  0000000000000018   I      14     6     8
  [ 8] .debug_info       PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00003424       0000000000000071  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [ 9] .rela.debug_info  RELA             0000000000000000  00003838       0000000000000060  0000000000000018   I      14     8     8
  [10] .debug_abbrev     PROGBITS         0000000000000000  00003495       0000000000000014  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [11] .debug_aranges    PROGBITS         0000000000000000  000034b0       0000000000000030  0000000000000000           0     0     16
  [12] .rela.debug_arang RELA             0000000000000000  00003898       0000000000000030  0000000000000018   I      14    11     8
  [13] .shstrtab         STRTAB           0000000000000000  000038c8       0000000000000085  0000000000000000           0     0     1
  [14] .symtab           SYMTAB           0000000000000000  000034e0       0000000000000228  0000000000000018          15    14     8
  [15] .strtab           STRTAB           0000000000000000  00003708       00000000000000fb  0000000000000000           0     0     1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), l (large)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)

There are no section groups in this file.

There are no program headers in this file.

Relocation section '.rela.text' at offset 0x3808 contains 1 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000fc0  001600000002 R_X86_64_PC32     0000000000000000 OPENSSL_ia32cap_P - 4

Relocation section '.rela.debug_line' at offset 0x3820 contains 1 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000030  000100000001 R_X86_64_64       0000000000000000 .text + 0

Relocation section '.rela.debug_info' at offset 0x3838 contains 4 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000006  000a0000000a R_X86_64_32       0000000000000000 .debug_abbrev + 0
00000000000c  000b0000000a R_X86_64_32       0000000000000000 .debug_line + 0
000000000010  000100000001 R_X86_64_64       0000000000000000 .text + 0
000000000018  000100000001 R_X86_64_64       0000000000000000 .text + 2e40

Relocation section '.rela.debug_aranges' at offset 0x3898 contains 2 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
000000000006  00090000000a R_X86_64_32       0000000000000000 .debug_info + 0
000000000010  000100000001 R_X86_64_64       0000000000000000 .text + 0

The decoding of unwind sections for machine type Advanced Micro Devices X86-64 is not currently supported.

Symbol table '.symtab' contains 23 entries:
   Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     0: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  LOCAL  DEFAULT  UND 
     1: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 
     2: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 
     3: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    4 
     4: 0000000000000000   483 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _x86_64_AES_encrypt
     5: 00000000000001f0   609 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _x86_64_AES_encrypt_compa
     6: 0000000000000520   465 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _x86_64_AES_decrypt
     7: 0000000000000700   737 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _x86_64_AES_decrypt_compa
     8: 0000000000000ae0   649 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    1 _x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_k
     9: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    8 
    10: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   10 
    11: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    6 
    12: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT   11 
    13: 0000000000000000     0 SECTION LOCAL  DEFAULT    5 
    14: 0000000000000460   177 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 AES_encrypt
    15: 0000000000000460     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 asm_AES_encrypt
    16: 00000000000009f0   184 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 AES_decrypt
    17: 00000000000009f0     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 asm_AES_decrypt
    18: 0000000000000ab0    35 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 private_AES_set_encrypt_k
    19: 0000000000000d70   541 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 private_AES_set_decrypt_k
    20: 0000000000000f90  1411 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 AES_cbc_encrypt
    21: 0000000000000f90     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 asm_AES_cbc_encrypt
    22: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND OPENSSL_ia32cap_P

No version information found in this file.
```

**EDIT 2:**

nm aes-x86_64.o produces following output.

```
0000000000000f90 T AES_cbc_encrypt
00000000000009f0 T AES_decrypt
0000000000000460 T AES_encrypt
0000000000000f90 T asm_AES_cbc_encrypt
00000000000009f0 T asm_AES_decrypt
0000000000000460 T asm_AES_encrypt
                 U OPENSSL_ia32cap_P
0000000000000d70 T private_AES_set_decrypt_key
0000000000000ab0 T private_AES_set_encrypt_key
0000000000000520 t _x86_64_AES_decrypt
0000000000000700 t _x86_64_AES_decrypt_compact
0000000000000000 t _x86_64_AES_encrypt
00000000000001f0 t _x86_64_AES_encrypt_compact
0000000000000ae0 t _x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key
```

**Edit 3:**

nm -a gives following output

```
0000000000000f90 T AES_cbc_encrypt
00000000000009f0 T AES_decrypt
0000000000000460 T AES_encrypt
0000000000000f90 T asm_AES_cbc_encrypt
00000000000009f0 T asm_AES_decrypt
0000000000000460 T asm_AES_encrypt
0000000000000000 b .bss
0000000000000000 d .data
0000000000000000 N .debug_abbrev
0000000000000000 N .debug_aranges
0000000000000000 N .debug_info
0000000000000000 N .debug_line
0000000000000000 n .note.GNU-stack
                 U OPENSSL_ia32cap_P
0000000000000d70 T private_AES_set_decrypt_key
0000000000000ab0 T private_AES_set_encrypt_key
0000000000000000 t .text
0000000000000520 t _x86_64_AES_decrypt
0000000000000700 t _x86_64_AES_decrypt_compact
0000000000000000 t _x86_64_AES_encrypt
00000000000001f0 t _x86_64_AES_encrypt_compact
0000000000000ae0 t _x86_64_AES_set_encrypt_key
```

Comment: Anything that is intended to be accessed externally should be declared in accompanying header files.

Comment: 1) yes, just find it in the binary yourself 3) once you got the offset you can of course just add it to the global symbol's address

Comment: @Jester, how to find the offset from binary ? I use readelf and nm, but not able to understand how to find offset from AES_cbc_encrypt to .LAES_Te/Td.

Comment: If `nm` output also contains `.LAES_Te` then you just subtract.

Comment: @Jester, nm output doesn't contain anything related to .LAES_Te/.LAES_Td.

Comment: Then the easiest is to do a search in a hex editor.

Comment: @bholanath: Did you use `nm -a` to include even debugger symbols?  That might show the "hidden" symbols unless they're totally stripped.

Comment: @PeterCordes, I have added output of nm -a , but no hidden symbol.

Comment: Oh right, the asm uses `.LAES_Te`.  `.Lname` makes a local label that doesn't appear even as a debug symbol.  I was getting mixed up with the other parts that used some `.globl` `.hidden` symbols.

Comment: Can I use objdump to find distance/offset of Data at .LAES_Te from AES_cbc_encrypt  ?

Answer (score 0):

If you hard-code an offset based on this version of the library, it could break with a different version that has any changes in `aes-x86_64.s`.

So you should add a `.globl foo` and `foo:` label to the `.s` at the position of the data you want to access, and declare it in C as `extern uint32_t foo[]`.

---

Then the normal code-gen mechanisms for accessing static data from a shared library will kick in.  (i.e. load the address from the GOT if necessary).

Also, unless you compile with `-fno-plt`, `&AES_cbc_encrypt` will be the address of the PLT stub / wrapper, not the actual function in the library.

---

**If you only need it to work with a specific build of the library**:

Then yes I think with `-fno-plt`, taking the address of a function in the library will compile/assemble to a load from the GOT, so you get the actual address after dynamic linking.  **`-fno-plt` is essential for this to work**.

It might be fairly far away if it's in another section (`.rodata` instead of `.text` probably) so your simple scan of 768 * 4 bytes may not find the table, though.

A better way to find the offset from a symbol you can use `&` on in C:

Use a debugger: single-step into a function that uses the data, and find what address it's loading from (`gdb`'s built-in disassembly should work).

Or disassemble the binary and look at the little-endian rel32 offset in a RIP-relative load or LEA of the table address.  (That offset won't be fixed-up at run-time).  Look at the asm source to find an instruction that references the hidden symbol you want, then find that instruction in the disassembly.

That will give you the distance in bytes from the end of that instruction to the table.  You can probably see the distance from that instruction to a symbol you can take the address of in C (like you're doing with the function pointer).  Also, the disassembler will fill in absolute addresses (relative to some arbitrary base) for load addresses, and for symbols / instructions, so you can subtract those.

Comment: @PeterCode. Thanks for your prompt reply. It is ok even it works with a particular version of library with hard-coded offset.

Comment: Modification of library is not acceptable in my case. Will -fno-plt option during compilation and then my method of accessing &AES_cbc_encrypt give access to data ?

Comment: @bholanath: I think maybe.  With `-fno-plt`, taking the address of a static function will compile/assemble to a load from the GOT of the actual address after dynamic linking.  But it might be fairly far away if it's in another section (`.rodata` instead of `.text` probably) so your simple scan of 768 * 4 bytes may not find it.

Comment: I use gdb and found in disassembly version that .LAES_Te is 0x590 and .LAES_Td is 0x11c3. However, I don't know how to use these two offsets to access data as I am getting segmentation fault error while accessing address more than p+330 where p = &AES_cbc_encrypt ( in both case with /without -fno-plt option).

Comment: @bholanath: You mean the last 4 bytes of a RIP-relative instruction were `90 05 00 00`?  That's the relative distance from *that* instruction to `.LAES_Te`.  Given the distance from that instruction to a symbol in the same section (like `&AES_cbc_encrypt`), you can calculate an offset from the function address to the data.  And/or you can check what the runtime absolute address is, and see if it matches your calculations.

Comment: last 4 bytes of a RIP-relative instruction were 90 05 00 00. How to calculate runtime absolute address ? I have calculated the offset from &AES_cbc_encrypt to RIP , to find offset upto .LAES_Te and .LAES_Td, but still it is showing some random values , majority are 0.

Comment: @bholanath: From the address of the *end* of that instruction, add `0x590`.  Or from the address of a symbol before that instruction, `0x590 + insn_end - symbol`, in bytes.  (Remember that these are byte offsets, but C pointer math is scaled by the type size, so just divide by 4 if the total byte offset is a multiple of 4)

Comment: I have divided the offset by 8 as the data is long , sizeof(long) returns 8 in my 64bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Even sizeof(long *) returns 8.

Comment: @bholanath: In the asm, each line defines two 32-bit `.long`s.  But sure, if those are two halves of a what's really a `uint64_t`, then treat it as such.